# JAX produces memory error for simple program on GPU

Tags: memory, gpu, jax

I installed JAX (pip install --upgrade "jax[cuda11_pip]" -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html) and even for a simple code like

```py
a = jnp.array([1,2,3])
a.dot(a)
```

I get the following error:

```
2023-09-08 10:12:55.791658: E external/xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:445] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
2023-09-08 10:12:55.791696: E external/xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:449] Memory usage: 8058437632 bytes free, 8513978368 bytes total.
```

It looks like a memory issue. I tried the tips mentioned here

https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gpu_memory_allocation.html

but to no success.

This is the result of nvidia-smi on my system:

```
NVIDIA-SMI 470.199.02   Driver Version: 470.199.02   CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   64C    P0    37W /  N/A |    364MiB /  8119MiB |      2%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

It seems strange to me that there seems to be a out of memory issue when it is just a single array.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is a memory issue; rather it looks like you have a mismatch between your CUDA and CUDNN versions.

One way to ensure your CUDA versions are compatible is to use the pip-based installation (see [JAX pip installation: GPU (CUDA, installed via pip, easier)](https://github.com/google/jax#pip-installation-gpu-cuda-installed-via-pip-easier)). This should ensure that you install mutually-compatible CUDA, CUDNN, and jaxlib versions on your system. Installing JAX using pip-installed CUDA looks something like this:

```
$ pip install --upgrade "jax[cuda12_pip]" -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html
```

It looks like this may be the approach you used; if so, you should check that your system path (e.g. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) is not pre-empting the pip-installed CUDA with a local version. There is some relevant discussion at https://github.com/google/jax/issues/17497.

If you want to use a local CUDA installation, you can follow [JAX pip installation: GPU (CUDA, installed locally, harder)](https://github.com/google/jax#pip-installation-gpu-cuda-installed-locally-harder), but then it is up to you to ensure that your CUDA, CUDNN, and jaxlib versions are mutually compatible. Installing JAX using local CUDA looks something like this:

```
$ pip install --upgrade "jax[cuda12_local]" -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html
```

but if you use this approach, be sure to read the details at the above link.

Comment: Thank you for your message. You were right and the problem was the CUDA/CUDNN mismatch. I fixed it by reinstalling it and checking the LD_LIBRARY PATH.